# Implementing horizon charts in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to implement horizon charts in matplotlib (see: http://square.github.com/cubism/)

The basic idea is that you display a time series in narrow aspect ratio, and as values increase (beyond the y-axis limit), they start back up from the bottom in a darker color (think of old Atari games when you'd go past the top of the screen and pop out in the bottom).

My basic approach is to divide the y-data into chucks and plot each vertical group on a new axes using `ax.twinx()` and setting the limits appropriately.

For positive or negative data alone, this seems to be working well.

Positive:

[image: positive horizon chart]

Negative:

[image: negative bar chart]

But for some reason, doing both screws up:

```
# setup the environment
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi*4, 137)
y = (2*np.random.normal(size=137) + x**2)

# reflect everything around the origin
xx = np.hstack([-1*x[::-1], x])
yy = np.hstack([-1*y[::-1], y])

# function to do the plot
def horizonPlot(ax, x, y, nfolds=3, inverty=False, color='CornflowerBlue'):
    axes = [ax]
    if inverty:
        ylims = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), nfolds + 1)[::-1]
    else:
        ylims = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), nfolds + 1)

    for n in range(1, nfolds):
        newax = axes[-1].twinx()
        axes.append(newax)

    for n, ax in enumerate(axes):        
        ax.fill_between(x, y, y2=ylims[n], facecolor=color, alpha=1.0/nfolds, zorder=n)
        ax.set_ylim([ylims[n], ylims[n+1]])
        ax.set_yticklabels([])
        ax.set_yticks([])

        if inverty:
            ax.invert_yaxis()

    ax.set_xlim([x.min(), x.max()])
    return fig

fig, baseax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6.5,1.5))
posax = baseax.twinx()
negax = posax.twinx()
fig = horizonPlot(posax, xx, np.ma.masked_less(yy, 0), inverty=False, color='DarkGreen')
fig = horizonPlot(negax, xx, np.ma.masked_greater(yy, 0), inverty=True,   color='CornflowerBlue')
for ax in fig.get_axes():
    ax.set_yticklabels([])

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The bad chart (notice the lack of multiple layers on the positive side):

[image: both horizon charts]

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: I thought about implementing cubism as well. I will definitely use this code as soon as it runs; Thanks a lot already. Could you explain, what the `zstart` parameter does? when I run this on my machine, it looks even worse, the higher layers are plotted outside the chart it throws `tight_layout : falling back to Agg renderer`

Comment: @MillaWell whoops that was a vestigial kwarg left over from a failed experiment. I though that the zorders were somehow to blame, so zstart allowed me so make sure that the negative and positive layers were far away from each other. Suffices to say that this did not help and i've removed it from the post. As for the Agg-fallback -- comment out the call to `fig.tight_layout`. Does that help?

Comment: it does help, and actually: could you tell me whats wrong with your "bad chart"? if the only mistake is that the green layers are not plotted upon eachother, this works fine on my machine! Did you try to comment out the tight_layout? [pic](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=51c7ko&s=6)

Comment: @MillaWell yes the problem is that the layering is failing on the positive side. Essentially I would like the first two charts to be stacked on top of each other.

Comment: well, then seems to work for me =) are you willing to pubish this code, or do you mind if I use it?

Comment: it's all yours! (would you mind trying your link again? it's redirecting me to a generic recent uploads page). And if I can get this working the way I'd like, I'll make more general and try to get a PR in to either pandas or matplotlib

Comment: Yes sorry, did redirect it. I unfortunately got no clue why its working on my computer (and on yours not).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25392/discussion-between-milla-well-and-paul-h)

Comment: the problem might be related to the plotting itself, since by plotting the negative values first (switching the two `horizonPlot` lines), now the positive values are ok but not the negative values. I cannot figure what's wrong though ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually do not know, why yours is not working, because on my computer it works fine. But since I am really interested in this plotting, I tried to implement it on my own without all this fancy `twinx` stuff.

I just plot these areas on top of eachother, since this is actually the great thing about the plot. Thus I do not need to adjust the alpha, they just add up.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

def layer(y,height):
    neg=0.0;pos=0.0
    if y>0:
        if y-height>=0:
            pos=height
            y-= pos
        else : 
            pos = y
    elif y<0:
        if y+height<=0:
            neg=height
            y += neg
        else : 
            neg = -y
    return pos,neg

def horizonPlot(x,y,height=50.0,colors=['CornflowerBlue','DarkGreen']):
    alpha = .10
    vlayer = np.vectorize(layer)
    while (y != 0).any():
        l = vlayer(y,height)
        y -= l[0];y += l[1]
        fill_between(x,0,l[0],color=colors[0], alpha=alpha)
        fill_between(x,height-l[1],height,color=colors[1], alpha=alpha)

def main():
    x = np.linspace(0, np.pi*4, 137)
    y = (2*np.random.normal(size=137) + x**2)
    xx = np.hstack([-1*x[::-1], x])
    yy = np.hstack([-1*y[::-1], y])
    horizonPlot(xx,yy)
    show()
```

This looks like the following on my machine. Hope it works on yours, but I just use basic plotting methods.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works on my system with MPL 1.2. It's interesting that both implementations working on MPL 1.1. Hopefully I'll find time to do a `git bisect` and track down where the discrepancy. Also, I took your implementation and refined it just a bit. https://gist.github.com/phobson/5073171

Comment: For what it's worth, this is fixed in all later versions of matplotlib greater than v1.2.1

Comment: There's something wrong with this implementation. Try `y = np.array([0,100,-100,100,0]).T ;
horizonPlot(range(5), y)` -  the problem is that you have to add an x value between every pair of y values that crosses an axis.