# Plotly: How to fill area between lines?

Tags: python, plotly

I meet difficult in building horizon graph with `plotly`. I succeed in building this with `matplotlib.plotly` using demo code from [Implementing horizon charts in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167928/implementing-horizon-charts-in-matplotlib), but fail with `plotly` because I couldn't find any function to achieve `fill_between` in `plotly`.

I am wondering how to fill an area between two broken line in `plotly`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `fill=tozeroy` like this:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[0, 2, 3],
                         mode = 'lines',
                         fill='tozeroy'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[3, 5, 4],
                         mode = 'lines',
                         fill='tonexty'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5.5, 6],
                         mode = 'lines',
                         fill='tonexty'))

fig.show()
```

Comment: Is there way to fill area between certain x-range for example only fill between x in [1.5,2.5]?